# App java se bloquea en Mac

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy aprendiendo Java pero tengo problemas cuando ejecuto el programa, se bloquea en Mac.
El programa es sencillo, un marco con una lámina y dentro de ella he creado dos cuadros de texto.

```
package graficos;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FocoEvento
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MarcoFoco mimarco = new MarcoFoco();
        mimarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class MarcoFoco extends JFrame
{
    public MarcoFoco()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(300,300,600,450);
        add(new LaminaFoco());
    }
}

class LaminaFoco extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setLayout(null);
        cuadro1 = new JTextField();
        cuadro2 = new JTextField();

        cuadro1.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);
        cuadro2.setBounds(120, 50, 150, 20);

        add(cuadro1);
        add(cuadro2);
    }
    JTextField cuadro1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField cuadro2 = new JTextField();
}
```

Cualquier otro ejemplo de los que he estado haciendo ninguno ha fallado, creo que puede fallar por los cuadros de texto (JTextField).

Si alguien me puede ayudar a ver si este código no se le bloquea en vuestro ordenador(para saber si falla Java en mi Mac) o ver dónde puede estar el fallo en porqué se bloquea se lo agradecería(para saber si es un fallo de código).

Cuando lo ejecuto tarda un poco, pero cuando hago clic en el cursor en los campos de texto se bloquea indefinidamente.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El programa se colgará en cualquier sistema operativo, quizá hasta tragarse todos los recursos de RAM de cualquier maquina en algún momento; explico:

En el panel `LaminaFoco`, usas el metodo `paintComponent` para instanciar y agregar los 2 `JTextField`, pero cuidado, cuando se hace el `add(cuadro1)` y `add(cuadro2)` al final se hace un llamado a `repaint()` que se traduce en volver a llamar a `paintComponent()` por lo cual se queda en un ciclo indefinido instanciando y agregando otros dos `JTextField`; este comportamiento lo puedes comprobar/debuggear con un simple contador el cual imprimes y verás como incrementa de manera frenética.

La solución mas común sería acomodar los componentes desde el constructor de `LaminaFoco`:

```
class LaminaFoco extends JPanel
{
    /*public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);*/
    public LaminaFoco() {
        setLayout(null);
        cuadro1 = new JTextField();
        cuadro2 = new JTextField();

        cuadro1.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);
        cuadro2.setBounds(120, 50, 150, 20);

        add(cuadro1);
        add(cuadro2);
    }
    JTextField cuadro1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField cuadro2 = new JTextField();
}
```